# How to automate Drag&Drop using SendInput

Tags: c++, c, winapi, automation, sendinput

I want to test a flash application running on browser. I need to drag pieces around in the application. I want to do this by simulating mouse movements using windows api.

Here is my navie solution to simulate a mouse drag:

```
            void MoveMouse(LPINPUT input, int x, int y) {
                input->type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                input->mi.dx = x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
                input->mi.dy = y*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
                input->mi.dwFlags =  MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
            }

            void LeftDownMouse(LPINPUT input, int x, int y) {
                input->type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                input->mi.dx = x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
                input->mi.dy = y*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
                input->mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            }

            void LeftUpMouse(LPINPUT input, int x, int y) {
                input->type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                input->mi.dx = x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
                input->mi.dy = y*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
                input->mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            }

            void DragMouse(LPINPUT inputs, int startX, int startY, int dropX, int dropY) {
                MoveMouse(&inputs[0], startX, startY);
                LeftDownMouse(&inputs[1], startX, startY);
                LeftUpMouse(&inputs[2], startX, startY);
                LeftDownMouse(&inputs[3], startX, startY);
                MoveMouse(&inputs[4], dropX, dropY);
                LeftUpMouse(&inputs[5], dropX, dropY);
            }

            int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
            {
                INPUT inputs [6] = {};
                                    // Assume there is a maximized window, mouse drags the window from 40, 10 to 100,100 coordinates.
                DragMouse(inputs, 40, 10, 100, 100);

                SendInput(6, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));


                Sleep(1000);

                return 0;
            }
```

This code mostly doesn't work, sometimes works, it has undefined behaviour. What could be the problem? How can i solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use a supported way to do this rather than faking input?

Comment: why don't you suggest something rather than ask me?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a specific reason for your choice of solution. Because it seems odd to me. So perhaps there is some motivation that I am not aware of behind your decision to fake input to get this done. Are you wedded to faking input, or are you prepared to consider other solutions?

Comment: I can use anything that works. The application lives on the web, and i need to test it live. Also i want to know how to fake mouse input in anyway i want.

Comment: OK. In that case do it with input faking. Good luck.

Comment: I would like to hear your solution please thank you.

Comment: Not at this question. You asked about input faking. You've reaffirmed that in comments. So this question is about input faking.

Comment: @user3552580: what makes you think the behavior is undefined exactly? What have you tried to do so far to troubleshoot it? And why are sending a left down/up before then sending a left drag?

Comment: Explained in the comment, i am trying to drag a maximized window. You have to double click the window first, then drag. so down/up/down/move/up. So it sometimes moves the window, sometimes only the mouse moves but not the window.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with drag and drop, although my results were consistent in that the mouse was moving but not the item being dragged.

Your `MoveMouse` function is missing the `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` flag.  Try `input->mi.dwFlags =  MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;`

Without the flag setting you are just asking the mouse to move without the left mouse button being down.

**Edit**

I just checked my implementation and I don't set coordinates when pressing or releasing the mouse buttons.  Only when moving.

As for variance in results, you may stop these by zeroing out the `INPUT` before setting fields.